# Is there a technical reason why the Arduino Uno has such a distinctive board shape?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Why does the Arduino Uno have that slanted shape at the right of the board? Is there a particular technical reason for this design choice, or was it just for esthetics?

[image: Arduino Uno]

Comment: “A lot of the design choices are weird for a real engineer,” Banzi says with a knowing laugh, “but I’m not a real engineer, so I did it in a silly way!” https://spectrum.ieee.org/geek-life/hands-on/the-making-of-arduino

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of the very few "why" questions that actually has an [official answer](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,2022.0.html):

> Arduino shape... Sep 10, 2007, 11:41 am Why are the arduino board
> shaped the way they are (with that "bump" on one side) instead of
> being a plain rectangle?
>
> Just curious...

> Re: Arduino shape...
> #2 Sep 10, 2007, 04:04 pm thanks mellis :)
>
> Remember that Arduino started as a tool for designers.... and plain
> green rectangles are sooo boring.... only an engineer would find a
> green rectangle exciting :)
>
> so we decided to give it a special shape... david quartielles came up
> with the shape and I picked the colour
>
> massimo

As an aside, the top left mounting hole is uncomfortably close to the female connector, unfortunately.

Comment: the top left hole is close because in R3 they added pins to the header. it is not the original design

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find a explanation, but, as engineer, I believe in two possibilities:

1. Mechanical, because for better fixation. You may then ask me, 'why, then, are there not only three holes, instead of four?' Again for mechanical reasons. Only three holes would leave the edges of the board susceptible to bend and risk physical breakage (breaking). With four holes, better stability in fixing and prevention of mechanical failures.
2. If the hole in the lower right corner was placed farther to the left, it would cut the track of analog channel 5. Therefore, for reasons of space, I believe the hole has stayed there.